# On android back button press navbar not refreshing active class immediately

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Webapp using chrome(android) and on pressing back button(android) double items are active and click outside removes old active in navbar.

Tried to add [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }". It does not help.

```
<div class="row navbar-bottom-row">          
   <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" class="col navbar-bottom-item">Home</a>                 
   <a routerLink="/myjobs" routerLinkActive="active" class="col navbar-bottom-item">Link</a>
   <a routerLink="/confirm" routerLinkActive="active" class="col navbar-bottom-item">Link</a>
   <a routerLink="/signup" routerLinkActive="active" class="col navbar-bottom-item">Link</a>                              
</div>
```

Comment: is this just a web app or are you packaging it in something like cordova?

Comment: No its just webapplication. No mobile app. Using chrome in android.

Comment: 'click outside removes old active in navbar' - Are you sure that it's not just the `:focus` or `:active` style that is misleading you?

Comment: :hover was the issue. But now i lost hover effect on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Touch screen needs no hover, so i apply hover only to mouse devices by media query like this.

```
@media (pointer: fine) {
  .navbar-bottom-item:hover {
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
  }
}
```